# Make a java client to connect to spring boot websocket with spring security

Tags: spring, maven, spring-boot, spring-security, websocket

I am trying to make a java websocket. Project is having Spring Security enabled. When I am trying to connect to websocket, I am getting following error

> The HTTP response from the server [200] did not permit the HTTP upgrade to WebSocket

Pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>iot</groupId>
<artifactId>websocket</artifactId>
<version>0.1.0</version>
<packaging>war</packaging>
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.7.RELEASE</version>
</parent>
<properties>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
</properties>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-websocket</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-messaging</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.microsoft.azure.sdk.iot</groupId>
        <artifactId>iot-device-client</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.32</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.rxtx</groupId>
        <artifactId>rxtx</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.7</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <!-- Joda-Time -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>joda-time</groupId>
        <artifactId>joda-time</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <!-- To map JodaTime with database type -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jadira.usertype</groupId>
        <artifactId>usertype.core</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.0.CR1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
        <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.json</groupId>
        <artifactId>json</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-websocket</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.googlecode.json-simple</groupId>
        <artifactId>json-simple</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.neovisionaries</groupId>
        <artifactId>nv-websocket-client</artifactId>
        <version>2.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-pool</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-pool</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
        <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <!-- Added Last -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
        <version>3.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-httpclient</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-httpclient</artifactId>
        <version>3.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-core</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
        <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.servlet.jsp-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-data-commons</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <!-- Azure -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.microsoft.azure.sdk.iot</groupId>
        <artifactId>iot-service-client</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.23</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.microsoft.azure.sdk.iot</groupId>
        <artifactId>iot-device-client</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.32</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
        <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.microsoft.azure</groupId>
        <artifactId>azure-servicebus</artifactId>
        <version>0.9.7</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>

<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>spring-releases</id>
        <name>Spring Releases</name>
        <url>https://repo.spring.io/libs-release</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>
<pluginRepositories>
    <pluginRepository>
        <id>spring-releases</id>
        <name>Spring Releases</name>
        <url>https://repo.spring.io/libs-release</url>
    </pluginRepository>
</pluginRepositories>
```

Websocket Security Configuration

```
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.messaging.MessageSecurityMetadataSourceRegistry;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.socket.AbstractSecurityWebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer;

@Configuration
public class WebSocketSecurityConfig extends AbstractSecurityWebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer {

@Override
protected void configureInbound(MessageSecurityMetadataSourceRegistry messages) {
    messages
            .nullDestMatcher().authenticated()
            .simpSubscribeDestMatchers("/datasocket","/ehmdatasocket").permitAll()
            .anyMessage().permitAll(); 
}
@Override
protected boolean sameOriginDisabled() {
    return true;
}
}
```

Websocket Server Configuration

```
import java.util.Map;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.http.server.ServerHttpRequest;
import org.springframework.http.server.ServerHttpResponse;
import org.springframework.http.server.ServletServerHttpRequest;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.HandlerMapping;
import org.springframework.web.socket.WebSocketHandler;
import org.springframework.web.socket.config.annotation.EnableWebSocket;
import org.springframework.web.socket.config.annotation.WebSocketConfigurer;
import org.springframework.web.socket.config.annotation.WebSocketHandlerRegistry;
import org.springframework.web.socket.server.HandshakeInterceptor;

import com.ey.iotsphereeg.websocket.ServerWebSocketHandler;

@Configuration
@EnableWebSocket
public class WebSocketConfig implements WebSocketConfigurer {


    public void registerWebSocketHandlers(WebSocketHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addHandler(new ServerWebSocketHandler(), "/datasocket");

    }
}
```

Websocket server handler

```
import org.json.simple.JSONObject;
import org.json.simple.parser.JSONParser;
import org.json.simple.parser.ParseException;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import org.springframework.web.socket.CloseStatus;
import org.springframework.web.socket.TextMessage;
import org.springframework.web.socket.WebSocketSession;
import org.springframework.web.socket.handler.TextWebSocketHandler;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.concurrent.CopyOnWriteArrayList;

@Component
public class ServerWebSocketHandler extends TextWebSocketHandler {
    public List<WebSocketSession> sessions = new CopyOnWriteArrayList<>();

    @Override
    public void handleTextMessage(WebSocketSession session, TextMessage message)
            throws InterruptedException, IOException {
        //System.out.println(message.getPayload());
        JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();
        Object obj = null;
        try {
            obj = parser.parse(message.getPayload());
        } catch (ParseException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
        JSONObject jsonObject = (JSONObject) obj;
        //int size = sessions.size();
        if (!jsonObject.containsKey("test"))
            sendAll(message);
    }

    @Override
    public void afterConnectionEstablished(WebSocketSession session) throws Exception {
        // the messages will be broadcasted to all users.
        System.out.println(session.toString());
        //test.session = session;
        sessions.add(session);
        int s = sessions.size();
        System.out.println(s);
    }

    @Override
    public void afterConnectionClosed(WebSocketSession session, CloseStatus status) throws Exception {
        // the messages will be broadcasted to all users.
        sessions.remove(session);
    }

    @Override
    public void handleTransportError(WebSocketSession session, Throwable exception)throws Exception {
        // the messages will be broadcasted to all users.
        sessions.remove(session);
    }

    public void sendAll(TextMessage message) {
        try {
            int size = sessions.size();
            System.out.println(size);
            ArrayList<WebSocketSession> closedSessions = new ArrayList<>();
            for (WebSocketSession session : sessions) {
                if (!session.isOpen()) {
                    System.err.println("Closed session: " + session.getId());
                    closedSessions.add(session);
                } else {
                    System.out.println(message.getPayload());
                    session.sendMessage(message);
                }
            }
            sessions.removeAll(closedSessions);
        } catch (Throwable e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Websocket Client

```
import javax.websocket.ClientEndpoint;
import javax.websocket.OnError;
import javax.websocket.OnMessage;
import javax.websocket.OnOpen;
import javax.websocket.Session;

@ClientEndpoint
public class MyClient {
    @OnOpen
    public void onOpen(Session session) {
        System.out.println("##### Websocket Client Connected to endpoint: " + session.getAsyncRemote());

    }

    @OnMessage
    public void onMessage(String message) {
      //  System.out.println(message);
    }

    @OnError
    public void onError(Throwable t) {
        t.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Now when I am trying to connect without Spring Security enabled, It is working but when Spring boot Security is enable, I am not able to make handshake.

I tried reading documentations and tried to search on internet for long, but I didn't get proper solutions.